# Differential Equation Model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let's say we have a question like:

As the salt KNO3 dissolves in methanol, the number x(t) of grams of the salt in a solution after t seconds satisfies the differential equation $ x'=0.8x-0.004x^2 $.

How does one find the maximum amount M of the salt that will ever dissolve in the methanol?

Comment: What can you say about $x'$ when the salt stops dissolving in the methanol?

Comment: The rate of salt being dissolved or x' is equal to zero?

Comment: Yup, so then you get the equation $0.8x - 0.004x^2=0$, which you can then solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one looks at $x'(t)$, one observes the following facts:

1.)  $x'(0 \, \text{grams}) = 0$;

2.) $x'(200 \,  \text{grams}) = 0$;

3.)  for $0 < x < 200 \,  \text{grams}$, $x'(t) > 0$; the salt is going *into* the alcohol;

4.)  for $x > 200 \,  \text{grams}$,  $x'(t) < 0$; the salt is coming *out* of solution.

Note that, by (2), if $0 \,  \text { grams} < x < 200 \,  \text {grams}$ initially, $x$ can never increase beyond $200 \,  \text{grams}$  since $x'(t) = 0$ there.  So assuming we start with $x$ as in (3), the salt will continue, on the net, to *enter* the solution, at an ever decreasing *rate* as $x$ gets close to $200 \,  \text{grams}$, so that $x(t) \to 200  \, \text{grams}$ as $t \to \infty$.  Eventually, the amount of salt in solution will be indistinguishable from $200 \,  \text{grams}$, but never more.  The model predicts a maximum observable amount $x = 200 \,  \text{grams}$, provided $x$ starts off as in (3).

Hope this helps.  Cheers, and

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $x' = 0.8x−0.004x^2 = x(0.8 - 0.004x)$ has two roots at $x=0,200$. Hence, we know that $x'>0$ if $0<x<200$ and $x'<0$ if $x<0$ or $x>200$.

Now suppose that we start with an initial amount of $x(0)=x_0 \geq 0$. Then there are three cases to consider.

**Case 1:** If $x_0 = 0$ or $x_0 = 200$, then the amount will stay constant, so $M=x_0$.

**Case 2:** If $0<x_0<200$, then the amount will steadily increase towards the stable solution of $x=200$, so $x$ gets arbitrarily close to $200$.

**Case 3:** If $x_0 > 200$, then the amount will steadily decrease towards the stable solution of $x=200$, so $M = x_0$.